# Understanding android UDP server app code

Tags: android, udp

I'm novice with both android and Java. I'm trying to develop a very simple UDP server as my first android app (the second one if consider Hello World!).
I've collected the code from the web and this is the result:

```
package com.example.androidsocketserver;


import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public void updateTextView(String toThis) {

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
    textView.setText(toThis);

    }

private MyDatagramReceiver myDatagramReceiver = null;

protected void onResume() {
    myDatagramReceiver = new MyDatagramReceiver();
    myDatagramReceiver.start();
}

protected void onPause() {
    myDatagramReceiver.kill();
}

private class MyDatagramReceiver extends Thread {
    private boolean bKeepRunning = true;


    public void run() {
        String message;
        byte[] lmessage = new byte[200];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(lmessage, lmessage.length);

        try {
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(2500);


            while(bKeepRunning) {
                socket.receive(packet);
                message = new String(lmessage, 0, packet.getLength());                  
                if (message != null) {
                    updateTextView(message);
                    message = null;
                }       
            }
            if (socket != null) {
                socket.close();
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public void kill() { 
        bKeepRunning = false;
    }


}
}
```

Unfortunately the application is stopped as soon I launch it, but I don't understand why.
Is there someone so kind to help me to understand what I missed. I tryed with the emulator and with a real device obtaining the same result.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Add the stacktrace in your question.

Comment: Sorry but with the code I posted, I get no messages in Logcat (I mean the e.printStackTrace() instruction is not executed, i.e. no exception is catched in the run method). I belive the exception that close the app occurs before the call of "run", but I've no idea where place a staketrace instruction. Can you suggest me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whithout the error is very difficult to know were is the fault but try changing your receiver class to an async task

```
public class ReceiverBroadcastAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer ,String > {
boolean running = true;
Context context;
//public int counter = 1;
public ReceiverBroadcastAsyncTask(Context context) {
    this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
/////HERE YOUR CODE
}
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    //do whatever...nothing is required just pass a result on finish
}
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... Progress)
{
///you can pass data on here on the task progress to inform about the status 
}
}
```

From your Activity you can call your async task like this

```
new ReceiverBroadcastAsyncTask(this).execute(); ///this refers to context
```